# Black Screen after Changing NOOBS Skin

Tags: noobs

I installed NOOBS on my Raspberry Pi 3 and it worked fine until I decided to change the skin, which caused a system crash.

After restarting, the only thing visible is a black screen. However, I can still see and move the mouse cursor around the screen.

Is there some way to reset the skin without reinstalling the system?

*Note*: I do not have access to an SD Card Reader at the moment so I cannot easily reinstall the system.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no factory reset. You will have to either:

1. Pop the SD card into your computer, access the files on it and undo all the changes you've done
   or
2. Pop the SD card into your computer, format it and reinstall from scratch
   or
3. Make a bootable USB drive for your Pi and use that to access your SD card and fix it by either #1 or #2 above.

Answer (score 1):

Connect a Keyboard to the Raspberry PI, and change the TTY (Terminal) in order to switch from the GUI to a Shell

`CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1`

This should give you a login prompt. Login with your user and uninstall the skins or reconfigure to use a default skin.

*Note*: This terminal will be a shell (Command Prompt), so you will have to determine the commands needed to uninstall or configure skins.

---

Linux Kernel has a certain number of "default terminals" (tty), typically this number is 7.

By convention the system boots and the GUI  runs on `tty7`. The "X Window System" (GUI) runs inside this terminal.

However, the other terminals 1-6 are still available to be used for other purposes. Sometimes these can be used to running multiple GUI Sessions, but they can also be used to recover the GUI system

The standard keyboard-command to switch tty is `CTRL`+`ALT`+(`F1`-`F7`)

`CTRL`+`ALT`+`F7` will take you back to the GUI terminal (`tty7`)